# Patchwork not following layout correctly

Tags: r, ggplot2, patchwork

I want four equally sized panels on the second row of my plot but the output is not matching the layout I specify.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

set.seed(1)
df<-data.frame(x=rnorm(10),y=rnorm(10))
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x,y=y)) +
  geom_point()

layout <- "
AAABBBBB
CCDDEEFF
"

p + p + p + p + p + p + plot_layout(design = layout)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will produce the correct output (adapted from [here](https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork/issues/165))

```
(p + p + plot_layout(widths = c(3,5))) /
  (p + p + p +p + plot_layout(widths = c(2,2,2,2)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using different layout design per row:

```
(p + p + plot_layout(design = "AAABBBBB")) /
  (p + p + p + p + plot_layout(design = "CCDDEEFF"))
```

[image]